# HTML file input form shows whole path for selected file unlike VBScript

Tags: html, vbscript

First sorry for bad title, if anyone can name this question better please do.

I have this HTML file:

```
<html>
  <form action='' method='post'>
    <input id='inbox' type='file' />
    <input id='outbox' type='button' onclick='alert(inbox.value);' 
      value='submit' />
  </form>
</html>
```

when I open it with IE, then browse for a file and click "submit" button, I'm alerted with full path to selected file. But if I try to script same with VBScript:

```
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Offline = True
IE.Navigate "about:blank"

Do
Loop While IE.Busy

html = "<html>" &_
       "  <form action='' method='post'>" &_
       "    <input id='inbox' type='file' />" &_
       "    <input id='outbox' type='button' onclick='alert(inbox.value);'" &_
       "      value='submit' />" &_
       "  </form>" &_
       "</html>"

IE.Document.write html
IE.Width = 0
IE.Height = 0
IE.Document.All("inbox").Click
IE.Document.All("outbox").Click
```

I am alerted with infamous `c:\fakepath\file.ext` message.

Does anyone have an idea why is this or even better how to overcome it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your last comment - "I want file open dialog that will return full path and would work on XP and 7", and as I see you want to call this dialog in WSH environment, then you can use CommonDialog Control. This control is disabled in Windows 8, but works fine up to Windows 7, as you intend. Need to note that on 64-bit Windows by default .VBS files executed as 64-bit process, but that control is 32-bit, for that reason I include in my example code and function that restart the script as 32-bit process.

```
Call Force32bit

With CreateObject("MSComDlg.CommonDialog")
    .Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    .InitDir = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("MyDocuments")
    .MaxFileSize = 256
    .Flags = &H80000 + &H4 + &H8
    .ShowOpen
    If Len(.FileName) Then
        WScript.Echo .FileName
    Else
        WScript.Echo "Canceled"
    End If
End With

Sub Force32bit()
    Dim sWinDir, sSys64, sSys32, oShell
    Set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    sWinDir = oShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%WinDir%")
    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        sSys64 = .BuildPath(sWinDir, "SysWOW64")
        If Not .FolderExists(sSys64) Then Exit Sub
        sSys32 = .BuildPath(sWinDir, "System32")
        If sSys32 = WScript.Path Then
            oShell.CurrentDirectory = sSys64
            oShell.Run "wscript.exe " & Chr(34) & _
            WScript.ScriptFullName & Chr(34), 1, False
            WScript.Quit
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a security setting in IE, you can circumvent it by starting your html as a hta like this

```
Set wShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExec=wShell.Exec("mshta.exe ""about:<input type=file id=FILE><script>FILE.click();new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);close();resizeTo(0,0);</script>""")
MsgBox oExec.StdOut.ReadAll
```

Comment: Both HTML file and VBScript output should be under same security settings when executed, AFAIK. I know about the snippet you posted, and although it's nifty trick, it's also ugly with window pop flicker upon dialog exit, so I don't consider it.

Comment: i tested it and had no pupup other than the browse window and the messagebox. do you juyst want a dialog to get the path to a files ? then there are multiple ways..

Comment: Here I see flicker after dialog closes, while none if I use code similar to snippet from my question. Yes, I want file open dialog that will return full path and would work on XP and 7, and while XP offers `UserAccounts.CommonDialog`, 7 doesn't seem to have acceptable solution, from googling around.

Comment: Hi Peter, I've used this solution, it works well. But how can I change it for Save as dialog?

Comment: sorry no, I stopped using vbscript in favour of Ruby, Grtz